# Design appearance programmatically or graphically, which one is better?

Tags: ios

I'm learning many features of ios programming, but since I'm a beginner I don't know if it's better to design my appearance programmatically or graphically.

For example, should I make a view in code or should I drag it to my storyboard?

Should I set its size and position programmatically or graphically?

Which one is actually used in projects?

Specially considering the new Auto Layout and Size Classes feature in Xcode6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking into iOS development as a bit of a hobby then I'd recommend sticking to the graphical tools. These are faster to learn and will let you build your app in a shorter time if you are just beginning.

If you want to work on a large project in a professional environment or in a large team, then a 100% code project is usually desired.

If you pull apart some of the largest apps on the AppStore from huge companies, you'll see they don't use interface builder (IB) files. Take a look at Facebook, Spotify, Dropbox etc etc.

Some reasons include (but not limited to):

- **Ease of flow**: A complicated app UI in interface builder can seem like a blackbox sometimes, whereas code is usually easier to follow
- **Simpler merging**: If you have multiple developers working on the same UI file, merges can be a nightmare and more difficult compared to a source file
- **Finding problems**: If a problem exists in a pure code project then the problem is right there in the code. Locating problems in an IB file can be tough, depending on how buried it is. Also Xcode's 'find' tool doesn't search through IB files
- **Code runs faster**: You probably wont notice the speed but it is an advantage

Some boast the speed of coding using the graphical tools, and it's true that initially it will take you much longer than the code you're not yet familiar with. If you stick with it then you'll be able to write apps just as fast.

Answer (score 1):

For auto layout and layout constraints it is best you use graphical tools because it is definitely future proof. You can do the same thing with code but it takes a whole lot of time to do things when compared to the graphical way of doing it. At the end of the day it all comes to the developer's comfort zone and the app's requirements.

**A Small Point About Universal Apps:**

Universal app building is very comfortable when you choose graphical storyboarding and have separate stuff for iPhone and iPad (also there are bigger screen iPhones and iPads coming). If you choose to do all the UI stuff with code for an universal app you would end up writing a lot of if-else statements, like below

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    //Do iPhone stuff.
} else {
    //Do iPad stuff.
}
```

**Help from Interface Builder for Autolayouting**

> The easiest way to add, edit, or remove constraints is to use the
>   visual layout tools in Interface Builder. Creating a constraint is as
>   simple as Control-dragging between two views, or to add multiple
>   constraints at once, you simply use the various pop-up windows.

Quote from -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

You always have tools to save you even when you have messed up a lot with the constraints.

[image]

[image]

Some real good stuff,

http://carpeaqua.com/2014/05/09/why-you-should-use-interface-builder-with-auto-layout/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/51992/storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-code-the-great-debate